# ExtJS 6 - Bind proxy data to form

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs6

I have a proxy store that retrieves information from a webservice, I would like to show that information in a Panel in a way like a Grid, in which I set the "dataIndex" parameter to bind in the retrieved data.

How can I achieve this goal without extra coding, is that possible?

Something like this:

[image: Expected result]

Proxy Store:

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {

  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  alias: 'store.myStore',
  model: 'myModel',
  autoload: true,

  proxy: {
    type: <wsType>,
    url: <wsUrl>
  },
  scope: this

});
```

Panel:

```
Ext.define('<myPanel>', {

   extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

   ...

   store: Ext.create(<myStore>),

   ...


   items: [
   {
     xtype: 'titlePanel',
     cls: 'titlePanel',
     html: '<div class="titlePanel"><h1>My Title</h1></div>',
   },
   {
      xtype: 'form',
      layout: 'vbox',
      cls: 'whitePanel',
      items: [
      {
         xtype: 'panel',

         layout: 'column',
         items: [
         {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             displayField: 'name',
             dataIndex: 'name',
             fieldLabel: Ext.locale.start,
             name: 'start'
        },
   ...
```

Comment: Generally Store is used for Multiple Records, If you want to just display only record in display form. Why can't you define the proxy at model level and use Model.load to load the single record.

Comment: That's totally true! Thank you, do you have a simple example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Store for displaying a single Record. Proxy can be defined at a model level.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'contacts.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

Load the model either in view constructor/initComponent or controller init method, once loaded push the record to ViewModel.

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var me = this;
    MyApp.model.Contact.load(1, {
        success: function(record, operation) {
            me.getViewModel().set('contact', record);
        }
    })
},
```

Bind the model property to the display field

```
        items: [{
            name: 'firstName',
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            bind: '{contact.firstName}',
            xtype: 'displayfield'
        }]
```

And here is the fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17t2

Comment: Super awesome, that's what I was exactly looking for! Thanks.

Comment: What should I do in the case that I need this behavior but now the json returned contains 2 array fields to populate 2 different grids?